# Android, SpannableString, ArrayAdapter and Listview

Tags: android, listview, spannablestring

i am newbie to android and i got a question for you. I want to add icon to a text in a listview. I'm adding the rows(textview) to listview dynamically with below code. But the text doesnt contain the icon.

```
.
.
.
btnicon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txt.setText("   denemedene",BufferType.SPANNABLE);
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
dizi = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text);
list.setAdapter(dizi);
btnicon.setOnClickListener(click);
.
.
.
private OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnicon){
            SpannableString spans = new SpannableString(txt.getText());
            Drawable dra = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p1);
            dra.setBounds(0, 0, dra.getIntrinsicWidth() , dra.getIntrinsicHeight());
            ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(dra,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
            spans.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            dizi.add(spans.toString());
        }
    }
};
```

it is something about the toString method. Because when i change the

```
dizi.add(spans.toString());
```

line with

```
txt.setText(spans,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

it works, i can see the icon on text. I have no idea why it is not working with toString() method.

Any ideas?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for custom list adapter in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15272092/1752867

You can create your custom adapter like that and change checkbox component with imageView or ProgressBar in the layout

Comment: thanks for the reply but i got a little confusing about your code. how can i show the text and icon together with imageview or progressbar?

Comment: instead of checkbox write like this
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yourIcon" />

 
at that case your list shown icon + text side by side.

here is an other example : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

Comment: hmm i get it but this is not what i want. i dont want two different elements in listview. icon must be one of the text's characters(its positions not certain) so i use spannable string, its working for the textview that is not in the listview but no change for the textview in listview