# Dynamically adding textview to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to add textview to listview dynamically. Before adding im setting the text but in the listview text seems something like 'android.widget.TextView@45f...'

```
private ArrayAdapter<TextView> dizi;
private ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
dizi = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(this, R.layout.asd);
list.setAdapter(dizi);

TextView qwe = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
qwe.setText("txt");
dizi.add(qwe);

}
```

asd layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="5dp"

/>
```

I tried to change the textview element with linearlayout in asd layout file but it didnt work.

i cant figure it out. what do i have to do?

Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to add simple item layouts, which contain a textview...

Answer (score 3):

This is because the normal implementation of `ArrayAdapter` calls `toString()` on the Objects it is holding so that it can be sure they can be displayed.

Since the `ArrayAdapter` already uses `TextView`s to display the data, I suggest you change your Adapter so it is an `ArrayAdapter<String>`, then just add the String you want to display.

```
dizi = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.asd);
list.setAdapter(dizi);

dizi.add("txt");
dizi.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you want to change the layout, Extend `ArrayAdapter` and override the `getView()` method. This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) goes into a bit more depth.

A small example of an `ArrayAdapter` backed by a `List` of `String`s implementing some `Spannable`s:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

  LayoutInflater inflater;
  int resId;
  int layoutId;

  public ExampleAdapter(Context context,int layoutId, int textViewResourceId,
                        List<String> objects) {
    super(context, layoutId, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.layoutId = layoutId;
    this.resId = textViewResourceId; 
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    if (convertView == null)
      convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent,false);

    String text = getItem(position);
    Spannable s = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, text.length()/2, 0);
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), 0, text.length()/2, 0);
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.DKGRAY), text.length()/2, text.length(), 0);
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), text.length()/2, text.length(), 0);

    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(resId)).setText(s, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

To make an instance of it (assuming you're doing this from an Activity), what I did:

```
ArrayList <String> items = new ArrayList <String> ();
items.add ("Array Adapter");

ExampleAdapter dizi = new ExampleAdapter (YourActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,items);
list.setAdapter(dizi);

dizi.add ("your text");
dizi.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Actually i was trying to set the added textview text with icon and text together and i used spannable string for this but at the end something went wrong(i think because of toString method) and it didnt work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273771/android-spannablestring-arrayadapter-and-listview So i changed the way and tried this but nothing changed.

Comment: @tlgtkn Then you probably have a problem with your `getView()` method in the custom Adapter.

Comment: @tlgtkn you might want to actually post your `getView()` method for me to help you. Keep in mind that it is there that you have to assign the spannables and other UI elements to be displayed.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i dont have any getview method. i was not aware that there is a method like that. thank you for this i had better do some searching about it. any ideas from where i can start ?

Comment: @tlgtkn made an example of an ArrayAdapter with Spannables. You should also have a look at the tutorial I linked.

Comment: @tlgtkn Do you have any more questions?

Comment: so sorry for the very very late reply. but im working on another project. i will try your method as soon as possible and i'll let you know for any changes thanks..

Comment: @tlgtkn Did you ever get around to trying what I outlined in my answer?